# QGIS: SVG rotation based on attribut and symbol scaling in Legend tree

Tags: qgis

I´m trying to rebuild this SLD rule (the env part can be ignored)in QGIS 2.14:

```
<sld:PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
            ...
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:ExternalGraphic>
                <sld:OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="file:./position.svg"/>
                <sld:Format>image/svg+xml</sld:Format>
              </sld:ExternalGraphic>
              <sld:Size>10</sld:Size>
              <sld:Rotation>
                <ogc:Add>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>rot</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Function name="env">
                    <ogc:Literal>rotation</ogc:Literal>
                    <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Function>
                </ogc:Add>
              ...
```

[image]

Questions:

- Is it correct to choose mapunits and 10 as size to fulfill the UOM metre definition?
- Is the rotation convert correct by use the expression builder next to rotation -> choose edit and use `"rot" + 3` as expression? (ros is the name of a postgres attribut)?
- When choosing mapunits as SVG size the symbol gets also scaled in my layertree window when zooming in and out. How can I prevent this and show all symbols in layer-tree in one size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument in the ogc function "env" is a default value, so a better expression to use for rotation would be:

```
coalesce("ros", 3)
```

Ie, use "ros" where it exists, otherwise default to 3.

Re the symbol size in the layer tree - you can't change that. It will always scale to match the map.

Comment: Hi ndawson, thanks for your reply. But look there is also an add ogc:ADD shouldn´t the expression say `"rot" + coalesce("rotation", 3)` add rotation or 3 to rot (which is a postgis attribut)? further this env is variable substitution from geoserver (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/substitution.html) I´m unsure if this makes sense with QGIS, maybe with QGIS Server?